# Subgroups of additive rationals intersect.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we have two non trivial subgroups of addtive rational numbers, then their intersection is not trivial.

Sketch of proof: Both groups will have least positive integer and their lcm will belong to both groups.
Is my idea correct?

Comment: Yes, that will work, but there are simpler proofs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a proof that is more elementary than the one you mention, although it's in the same spirit.

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-trivial subgroups of $(\mathbb{Q} , +)$. Then there is a nonzero element $\frac{n}{m} \in A$ and a nonzero element $\frac{p}{q} \in B$. Since $A$ is a subgroup, any integer multiple of $\frac{n}{m}$ is in $A$ as well, and similarly for $B$. Therefore $pn = (pm) \cdot \frac{n}{m}$ is in $A$, and $pn = (qn) \cdot \frac{p}{q}$ is in $B$, so $pn \in A \cap B$. Since $\frac{n}{m}$ and $\frac{p}{q}$ are nonzero, it follows that $n , p \neq 0$ and since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a domain, we have $pn \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is fine. Here is a roadmap that captures the essence of your approach:

- If $H$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $\mathbb Q$, then $H \cap \mathbb Z$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $\mathbb Z$.
- If $A$ and $B$ are nontrivial subgroups of $\mathbb Z$, then so is $A \cap B$.